# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'display' in python

Tags: python, list

Error comes when i call the display function using class object
What should i do to overcome this ??

```
class A:

    def __init__(self, fname, lname, age):
        self.fname = fname
        self.lname = lname
        self.age = age

    def disply(self):
        fp = open("abc","r")

        for lines in fp:
            temp = lines.split(", ")[-1]
        fp.close()

        print a

a = [A("Taylor","Launter",22), A("James","bond",40)]
a.display()
```

Comment: `a` is a list, it doesn't have a display() method.

Comment: You might want to rename `def disply(self):` to `def display(self):`

Comment: @thefourtheye: renaming doesnot solve the problem

Comment: @GajGaj That alone will not solve the problem. Please look at my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = [A("Taylor","Launter",22), A("James","bond",40)]
a.display()
```

Now `a` is a list. Lists in python dont have `display` method.

What you might actually have wanted to do is to invoke `display` method of the object of `A`. If that is the case, you might want to do something like this

```
for currentObject in [A("Taylor","Launter",22), A("James","bond",40)]:
    currentObject.display()
```

**Edit** Your `display` method doesnt make any sense to me.

Comment: I am jus checking what comes

Answer (score 2):

You have a list of instances called `a`. `a` isn't the instance/s, it's a list.

You probably meant to do:

```
for myobject in a:
    myobject.disply() # Note "disply" instead of "display"
```

Comment: Surely you meant myobject.disply() ? Your code has the same problem as the OP.