# 'list' object has no attribute . Cant set a new attribute?

Tags: python

While I was framing the Title question I saw this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23642105/attributeerror-list-object-has-no-attribute-trackprogress and [AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'display' in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19462857/attributeerror-list-object-has-no-attribute-display-in-python)

but unlike those questions, this is similar to [Can't set attributes of object class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529002/cant-set-attributes-of-object-class) and not duplicate if and only if list doesnt behave like Object (reserved,read only attr)

I am able to set self.root and for the sake of checking self.rightChild & self.leftChild
so why does it throw this error?

```
class BinaryTree(list):
    ...:     def __init__(self,root_val,**kwarg):
    ...:         super(type(self),self).__init__()
    ...:         self.root = root_val
    ...:         self.rightChild = self.leftChild = None
    ...:         self = binaryTree(self.root)
    ...:         if 'left_child' in kwarg:
    ...:             self.leftChild = kwarg['left_child']
    ...:         if 'right_child' in kwarg:
    ...:             self.rightChild = kwarg['right_child']
    ...:             

b = BinaryTree(4,left_child = 5,right_child = 6)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-67-3ea564fafb06> in <module>()
----> 1 b = BinaryTree(4,left_child = 5,right_child = 6)

<ipython-input-66-208c402b07ce> in __init__(self, root_val, **kwarg)
      6         self = binaryTree(self.root)
      7         if 'left_child' in kwarg:
----> 8             self.leftChild = kwarg['left_child']
      9         if 'right_child' in kwarg:
     10             self.rightChild = kwarg['right_child']

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'leftChild'
```

binaryTree is some foo() function that works well and is not at all the concern.

Comment: Why are you basing your `BinaryTree` object on `list` instead of `object`?

Comment: @Amber because i want to inherit

Comment: @Amber just noticed error..previous comment is irrelevant now

Answer (score 2):

Apparently `binaryTree` returns a list, not a `BinaryTree`. So after the line `self = binaryTree(self.root)`, `self` is now a list and `self.leftChild = ...` thus produces an error as you cannot do that to a list.

> binaryTree is [...] not at all the concern

I'm pretty sure you're wrong about that.

Answer (score 1):

Change `class BinaryTree(list):` to `class BinaryTree(object):`. There's no need to base your tree object off of the list class.

(Also, overwriting `self` is probably not what you want to do. You probably instead want to assign to a subattribute of `self`.)